# In my wordpress website "Any one can register" automatically enabled

Tags: wordpress

Last month I saw on my email that about 8 new users are made on my word press website. I Opened my admin panel. There were 8 spam users with administrator rights. I immediately deleted all those users. And I unchecked Setting/General/"anyone can register" Membership option and changed "New user default role" to "Subscriber". I saved that and satisfied that everything is ok now. After 2 weeks I opened my email and amazed to see that again there are 25 new users created in my website. When I opened admin panel, there were again 25 new users with administrators' rights. Again the Setting/General/Membership/anyone can register option was checked and "New User default role" was set to "administrator".  Anybody help me out how the hackers are accessing my website and making users? How could I get rid of this attack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_register` hook to modify user registration process.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    // your code to get mail or information when new user register
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Also you can use plugin `Sucuri Security` for security your wordpress website.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/